# SQLite query with multiple condition

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to do something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = ? AND id IN (?, ?, ?)"
//selection: name + " = ? AND " + id + " IN (?, ?, ?)";
//selectionArgs[]: new String[] {"David", "2", "6", "7"});
```

it's not working: where is error?.
I am using:

```
query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
```

Comment: what do you mean by *it's not working* ?

Comment: cursor.getCount always 0, I'm not sure in selectionArges[]

Comment: the query looks fine. Are you sure, you have at least one row that satisfies your where clause ?

Comment: Okey, I'll debug. What do if args count will be different? {"David", "2", "6", "7", "9"} or {"David", "2", "6"}

Comment: the number of question marks have to match the size of `selectionArgs`

Comment: Are the ID values really strings?